# Git remote url: error while setting

Tags: git

I am very new to git and its command, experience in using Sourcetree. I asked my client to share a repository url they shared a command like this:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.cantiz.cloud/mrt/aeromart-thin-air.git
```

Just placed this command in a terminal and I got error given below:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have no idea on the next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run `git remote set-url` you must be within a git project in the terminal. If you already have the project, just `cd` to it's directory and run the command. Basically what it does is it instructs git what the remote is (i.e. where to push/fetch to and from).

If you don't have the project you can `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.cantiz.cloud/mrt/aeromart-thin-air.git`. This will create a directory with the project in the directory you're in, given the fact that you have access rights to access that repository.

Comment: Thank you for this help, It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if they added your public key to the repository (to get access via ssh)
2. To clone a repository use the following command `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.com/user/repositoryname.git`

For more information [read this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Comment: Thank you . I just followed Raul 's answer